# Запятая перед вопросом "и каким образом"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп

Почему перед союзом "и" не ставится запятая в предложении:

> Сможет ли это повлиять на моё поступление и каким образом?

Answer (score 4):

Запятая перед союзом **и** не ставится, если он объединяет **два вопросительных**, побудительных, восклицательных или назывных предложения.
Например: *Где же твоя деревня и ждут ли нас там?*

[Запятая перед союзом «И»](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

**Сможет ли это повлиять на моё поступление и каким образом?**
Сможет ли это повлиять на моё поступление? — первое вопросительное предложение;
каким образом [оно повлияет]? — второе (с пропуском главных членов).
Запятая перед **и** не требуется.